# Fill columns with 0 in pivot table pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

In one of column if it is missing how can I fill it with 0 instead of leaving it empty?

MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"day":[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                   "hour":[15, 15, 15, 15, 19, 20, 21],
                   "location":["A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"],
                   "numbers": [323, 2354, 124, 56, 45, 11, 44]})

df.pivot_table(index="location",
           columns=["day", "hour"],
           values = "numbers",
           fill_value=0,
           aggfunc="count").unstack().to_frame()
```

Which outputs:

```
                            0
day   hour    location  
                 A          2
                 B          1
       15        C          0
                 D          0

                 A          0 
                 B          0
       19        C          0
                 D          1

                 A          1
                 B          0
 3      20       C          0
                 D          0
```

and so on.. I've just left space in between for better readability.

As you can see hour goes from 15 to 19. I want to include hours= 16, 17, 18 which all locations and all rows in 0 column as 0.

So desired output would be:

```
                            0
day   hour    location  
                 A          2
                 B          1
       15        C          0
                 D          0

                 A          0
                 B          0
       16        C          0
                 D          0

                 A          0
                 B          0
       17        C          0
                 D          0

                 A          0
                 B          0
       18        C          0
                 D          0

                 A          0 
                 B          0
       19        C          0
                 D          1

                 A          1
                 B          0
 3      20       C          0
                 D          0
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's add `reindex` method with a `pd.MultIndex` created use the `from_product` of unique arrays and range of hours.

```
df.pivot_table(index="location",
           columns=["day", "hour"],
           values = "numbers",
           fill_value=0,
           aggfunc="count").unstack().to_frame()\
  .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['day'].unique(),
                                       np.arange(df['hour'].min(),
                                                 df['hour'].max()),
                                       df['location'].unique()]), 
           fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
        0
3 15 A  2
     B  1
     C  1
     D  0
  16 A  0
     B  0
     C  0
     D  0
  17 A  0
     B  0
     C  0
     D  0
  18 A  0
     B  0
     C  0
     D  0
  19 A  0
     B  0
     C  0
     D  1
  20 A  1
     B  0
     C  0
     D  0
```

Comment: Thanks but what if in some cases you need to 15 is not the mean. so maybe hours are from 13~20 but since all values are 0 in hour 13, 14 they are not appearing

Comment: Wait, I have multiple  days, it seems like it works only on first day.

Comment: It should if you use df['days'].unique() that will get multiple days.

Comment: Yup just figured it out. Thanks!